# Webpack : how to include the swiper.css int the bundle.js

Tags: webpack, swiper.js

I begin with webpack.

I would like to use the [swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper) library with webpack.

While I have no problem to use the js part, I can't find the way to include and use the css part.
I test severals require syntax but none works:

```
require("swiper/dist/swiper.css");
require("swiper.css");
```

Is that possible ? 
Is there a trick ?

Answer (score 2):

With the latest version, you use:

```js
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css'
```

Answer (score -3):

$ npm install swiper --save

// include css:

`import 'style!css!swiper/dist/css/swiper.css';`

// include js

`import 'swiper';`

The reason it was not working before is your style, css, sass loaders are set to exclude node_modules folder or set to include only certain folders.

Comment: He is looking to use web pack to build. http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#custom-build